# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable error 3

Tags: pandas, numpy, callable

A part of the code creating the problem is pasted below and the errors occurring during running the code is attached . Please help if someone got any idea to resolve this

```
from numpy import*
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from matplotlib.pylab import*
from numpy import matrix
from numpy import linalg
import scipy
import mcat
import ompc
from matplotlib import pyplot

#Radius of the wheel
rw = 3.25
#Distance between two wheels
lw = 11.2
#sampling time interval
deltat = 0.01
#The initial position of 3 landmarks and the robot (0,0,pi/2)
x=np.empty((100,1,9))
x(mslice[:], mslice[:], 1).lvalue = mcat([0, OMPCSEMI, 0, OMPCSEMI, 0, OMPCSEMI, 15.5, OMPCSEMI, 23.9, OMPCSEMI, 21.8, OMPCSEMI, 35.6, OMPCSEMI, 23.3, OMPCSEMI, 40.7])
#The center of 3 landmarks
L = mcat([15.5, 23.9, OMPCSEMI, 21.8, 35.6, OMPCSEMI, 23.3, 40.7])
D = mcat([1, 0, OMPCSEMI, 0, 1])
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Try and include your error msg as text, not an image: it's a lot easier to read and makes it indexable by search engines

Answer (score 1):

In the error I see a version issue, this cause the module to NOT return the Numpy Array.
Which Python version are you running?